# Required and RegularExpression Validators taking up space

Tags: asp.net

I'm having issues with asp.net's field validators taking up space on my page. I've searched around, and documentation says to use Display="Dynamic" to keep the validators from taking up space. When I use this however, the error messages are always displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

I just want the error messages to display when the user either clicks the "Save" button, or loses focus on a textbox. And I don't want the validators to take up space.

```
     <p>Please enter a new email:</p> 
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="255" ID="TextBoxEmail" />

     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
          ValidationGgroup="Email" 
          ErrorMessage="Please enter an email" 
          ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
         ValidationGroup="Email"
          ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail"                    
          ErrorMessage="Please enter valid email"
          runat="server"      
          ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />


      <p>Please re-enter your email:</p> 
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxEmail2" />


      <asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="Email" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClick="linkbuttonSave_Click"  />
```

Comment: *the error messages are always displayed*, what do you mean by that? using `display="dynamic"` with both validators didn't work for you?

Comment: @Sachin, when I set display="dynamic" to both validators, the error messages are always visible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only thing I notice in your code is you have a typo in `ValidationGgroup="Email"`. It should be `ValidationGroup="Email"`

Other than that, `Display="Dynamic"` works for me.

[image]

**After clicking, submit button -**

[image]

```
<p>
    Please enter a new email:</p>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="255" ID="TextBoxEmail" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="Email"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter an email" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" runat="server"
    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ValidationGroup="Email"
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid email" runat="server"
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="Dynamic" />
<p>
    Please re-enter your email:</p>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxEmail2" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="TextBoxEmail"
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail2" CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Must match." ValidationGroup="Email"></asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ValidationGroup="Email"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter an confirm email" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail2" runat="server"
    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" ValidationGroup="Email" runat="server" Text="Save"
    OnClick="linkbuttonSave_Click" />
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out that typo! I think I figured out what the problem was. I had given my validators a CssClass with a display:block. And I suppose it was always displying the css even with display="dynamic" in the validator controls.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the property Display to "Dynamic" or "none", the second one will cause the Error message to be displayed only in the validation summary.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work great by deleting the "ValidationGroup=.." . Havent looked what up what this does but it works great without it and not sure why it would be needed (given the validator controls have the control id of the email textbox)